# Add multiple texts to a single string and print when I want in Python

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I am trying to send arguments to add to a single string which I want to print at the end containing all the text as one string. I tried the following which is printing out for every send.

How can I just store it untill I want to print it all ?

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def printInfo(self,s):
        self.info=''
        self.info+=s
    def someFunction(self):
        #assume this list is being extracted from somewhere else unknown
        self.tempList = ['text1','text2','text4','text4','text5']
        for i in self.tempList:
            self.printInfo(i)
            self.anotherList=['text6','text7']
            for j in self.anotherList:
                self.printInfo(j)
        print self.info

stringTest = test()
stringTest.someFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using **join()** function:

```
" ".join(["multiple", "inputs", "should"])
```

This will concatenate a list of words using the specified separator.

Answer to the comment:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.info='' # You need to initialize the info variable only once
    def printInfo(self,s):
        self.info+=s
    def someFunction(self):
        #assume this list is being extracted from somewhere else unknown
        self.tempList = ['text1','text2','text4','text4','text5']
        for i in self.tempList:
            self.printInfo(i)
            self.anotherList=['text6','text7']
            for j in self.anotherList:
                self.printInfo(j)
        print(self.info)

stringTest = test()
stringTest.someFunction()
```

Comment: Hi Dainius, Thank you for the response

That's not exactly what I am looking for - probably I need to explain differently - I have a loop which extracts text from somewhere and on every iteration, I want to store/add to a single string - which at a later point I want to print out. Not sure if that made sense. 

I will try to come up with another sample to discribe the issue if possible.

Comment: I have edited the code close to what I am actually going for. But the output as you can see is `text 7`. but i need it as a complete string from text 1 to text 7